# Generalizations of Sperner's Lemma?

Tags: algebraic-topology, coloring

Consider colorings of n-dimensional complexes.
Given a complex $C$, and a coloring of $C$, a simplex $\alpha \in C$ is said **(n-x)-complete** with respect to this coloring if all its vertices receive *at least* $(n-x)$ colors.

Sperner's Lemma and the Index lemma relate the number of n-complete simplices in a complex with the number of n-complete simplices in its boundary.

I need to generalize this result to relate the number of $(n-x)$-complete simplices in a complex and their number in its boundary.

Does this generalization already exists ?
Any help is welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: It would be amazing if [sperners lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/44154/sperners-lemma) himself could answer this question =)

Comment: :) really ! is it so difficult ?
Is there any work on this subject, even an incomplete answer to the question ?